# gcc vs. clang: "invalid use of incomplete type" with std::declval and template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, sfinae

I have a method `fun` which is contained within a struct `Impl` for partial specialization. The check `is_derived_from_template` is used to find out whether a generic `Impl::fun` can be used for a type if it derives from a specific template. Otherwise, `Impl` is partially specialized explicitly.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Base{};

// Forward declaration
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

template <template<typename...> class T, typename U>
struct is_derived_from_template
{
private:
    template<typename... Args>
    static decltype(static_cast<const T<Args...>&>(std::declval<U>()), std::true_type{}) test(const T<Args...>&);
    static std::false_type test(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<U>()))::value;
};

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct Impl
{
    static void fun(T& x);
};

template <typename T>
struct Impl<T, typename std::enable_if<is_derived_from_template<Base, T>::value>::type>
{
    static void fun(T& base)
    {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <>
void Impl<Foo>::fun(Foo& t)
{
    std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
}

struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Base<int,double> {};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;

    Impl<Foo>::fun(foo);

    Impl<Bar>::fun(bar);
}
```

When compiling this code with gcc, I get the following error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool is_derived_from_template<std::vector, Foo>::value':
main.cpp:33:15:   required from here
main.cpp:15:48: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Foo'
     static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<U>()))::value;
                                                ^
main.cpp:5:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct Foo'
 struct Foo;
        ^
```

[<kbd>gcc live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51e15b5f3cd1602e)

However, clang compiles this without an error and the output is as expected:

```
Foo
Base
```

[<kbd>clang live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b781b4baab079a9)

1. Which of the two compilers is right?
2. How can I modify my code to get it to work with gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduced to

```
#include <utility>
void f(...);
class C;
using type = decltype(f(std::declval<C>()));
```

Compiles on Clang, errors on GCC.

I'm inclined to say that GCC is right here, because passing an object of class type via `...` requires copying, and you can't copy something with an incomplete type.

If you want to, you can use pointers instead in your SFINAE:

```
template <template<typename...> class T, typename U>
struct is_derived_from_template
{
private:
    template<typename... Args>
    static decltype(static_cast<const T<Args...>&>(std::declval<U>()), std::true_type{}) test(const T<Args...>*);
    static std::false_type test(...);
public:
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<U*>()))::value;
};
```

Although you should be cautious about allowing `is_derived_from_template` to be instantiated with an incomplete type, since it can easily lead to ODR violations if the complete type turns out to be derived from the specified template.

Answer (score 3):

1.`Clang` compiles a bit differently than traditional compilers like `GCC`. `GCC` would be right in the sense that it parses code 'traditionally' compared to `Clang`, and that you should define your types before using them.
You can find a comparison [here](http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html).

2.Changing:

```
// Forward declaration
struct Foo;
struct Bar;
```

to:

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar : Base<int,double> {};
```

Worked for me.